# Swift and SwiftyJSON - dump() not work

Tags: swift

try to use dump method on variable filled with JSON. But it doesnt work and i dont understand why

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var hoge: JSON?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
    if data != nil {
        hoge = JSON(data: data!)
        let count = hoge!["results"][0]["body"].stringValue
    println(count)
    }
}

func res() {
    dump(self.hoge)
}
}
```

can you please help me show what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, your code works for me, see my [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/1e4d6bae-2b21-4731-a61a-aa2fd958fd48/1934267ac6bf3cf1). Are you sure you're calling `res()` somewhere?

Comment: sorry my level of noobness so high so i messed everything up, and i really didn't have a call to res method anywhere :)

Comment: No problem. Have fun :)